# how to display tooltip for telerik RadRibbonSplitButton

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

I have RadRibbonSplitButton it contains Dropdown content of 3 items..want to display tooltip for the whole group.

```
            <telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton text = "search">
               <telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton.DropDownContent>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Header = "Search 1" Click="Search1_Click">
                        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton.DropDownContent>
           </telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton>
```

have 3 search items ..how to display the tooltip on the whole group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way...

```
       <telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton text = "search"   
                    telerik:ScreenTip.Description="{x:Static }"
                    telerik:ScreenTip.Title="{x:Static }">>
           <telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton.DropDownContent>
                 <telerik:RadMenuItem Header = "Search 1" Click="Search1_Click">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            </telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton.DropDownContent>
       </telerik:RadRibbonSplitButton>
```